# Получить перевод слова с сайта google translate в Питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, google-translate

У меня вот такой вопрос, что если есть сайт translate.google.com (например).
Ты же когда хочешь перевести слово, ты же должен вводить его в поле и потом он выдаст тебе результат. И вот у меня вопрос, что если я хочу получить перевод какого-нибудь слова через google translate то как я могу его так пропарсить через python?
Подскажите пожалуйста какие-нибудь библиотеки или статьи, потому что я не нашел, буду благодарен. )

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону библиотек grab и selenium.

Comment: @Avernial Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Если вы имели ввиду - парсить html код, передав в запрос GET параметр - слово для перевода, то в таком случае как google, так и яндекс не вернет вам желаемый перевод. Для этого есть платный API, может и бесплатный, который возращает удобный формат json строки. Подробнее о Google API можете прочитать где-то здесь https://cloud.google.com/translate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У Гугла есть официальная библиотека, можно ей воспользоваться: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries

Пример кода на Python можно посмотреть здесь:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/translate/usage.html

```
>>> from google.cloud import translate
>>> client = translate.Client()
>>> client.translate(['Me llamo Jeff', 'My name is Jeff'],
...                  target_language='de')
[
    {
        'translatedText': 'Mein Name ist Jeff',
        'detectedSourceLanguage': 'es',
        'input': 'Me llamo Jeff',
    }, {
        'translatedText': 'Mein Name ist Jeff',
        'detectedSourceLanguage': 'en',
        'input': 'My name is Jeff',
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

**вы можете использовать этот синтаксис, чтобы использовать googletrans с Python:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()

class UnsortedAttributes(HTMLFormatter):
    def attributes(self, tag):
        for k, v in tag.attrs.items():
            yield k, v
```

**пожалуйста, посмотрите эти две ссылки, коды готовы:**

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/example-google-translate-api-key-python-code-beautifulsoup.html

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/deepl-api-key-python-code-text-google-translation-beautifulsoup-languages-translate.html

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)